# Rails sunspot reindex - progress bar: Max must be a positive integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, reindex

I am trying use sunpost and I am failing during `rake sunspot:reindex` with this error:

**Error using progress bar: Max must be a positive integer**

This error occurs even if database is empty. 
I am using this: 
- ruby-1.9.3-p448  
- rails-3.2.18  
- sunspot_rails-2.1.1  
- sunspot_solr-2.1.1

I tried reboot system, restart sunpost:solr, remove solr folder from rails project and nothig worked, even remove gem progress_bar, but sunspot wont work without this gem

Any idea anyone?  
Thx for help

Comment: Did you solve this? Even I am facing same problem

Comment: Please check my answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26435813/error-using-progress-bar-max-must-be-a-positive-integer/33079551#33079551